# 2D Game Engine How Can I Organise Game Objects?

Tags: python, pygame

Good Evening (from Europe).

I'm trying to create a 2D game engine with python and pygame 
that will work
similar with the [Unity 3D](https://unity3d.com/), but you'll be able to create only 2D games.

To explain my problem i will show you some of my classes that you need
to know before i continue.

I have a class called **Sprite** which represents my game objects and the method that we care about is the **render** method. This method is been called
every frame per second and draws the image of the sprite object into the screen.
It also calls another method **update** which you can overwrite and create some
logic for your sprite object (I call it brains :p ). Also i have a class **Scene** where i store all my sprite objects into a linked list.

In order to render all my game objects of my scene i created a method inside my **Scene** class with the above algorithm:

```
#obj is a sprite object.
#Is been called every frame per second.
for obj in gameobjects:
    obj.render()
```

As you can see this is the simpliest way to render all the gameobjects of my scene. And here is where my problem begins. If we say that i have 10.000 game
objects into the scene this for loop will delay the frame causing lag problems.

One solution that i thought about was to render only the gameobjects that
i can see (gameobjects that are inside the window borders). That works well
but the problem is that i must check all the game objects which are into my
scene to be inside the window resolution and render only them. So i did something like this:

```
#This method is been called only every time there is a movement
#action into te game causing all the game objects to change position.
for obj in all_game_objects:
    if inside_resolution(obj):
        render_objects.append(obj)

#Is been called every frame per second.
for obj in render_objects:
    obj.render()
```

As you can see i still need to check all the gameobjects so i did not succeed a thing!

If i could somehow organise my game objects into a data structure like a binary tree and create some smart methods that will return only the game objects which
are inside the window resolution i could succeed a fast rendering system.

***So my entire problem is what data structure can i use to store my game objects?
A tree would be very fast but how could i know which game objects are inside the
screen resolution without checking them all?***

From what a have heard, modern game engines like unity3D are using trees to
render different areas of the scene (and theres where the view distance fits in).The thing is how this works.

I hope the description of my problem was enough.

Thanks for your patience :p

Comment: Quadtrees are a relatively common way of quickly determining which objects are within certain parts of space.

Comment: Have you *tried* rendering 10000 objects and know *for sure* that the rendering loop is the main bottleneck of your application? If you haven't, then this is just another case of [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Most rendering libraries are efficient enough to render 10000s of objects without a hitch. If you are ***completely** sure* that the rendering loop is causing a performance bottleneck, then only should you make others vest their time in helping you.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to look at doing all your rendering in a different thread if it's actually the bottleneck. The thing that you did is actually the easiest way to improve performance *if* it's the problem. You will **have** to iterate through each object and run its update method anyway, so why not this small check? You could actually move all your rendering code to a `Camera` or similar class, and each object can notify each Camera if it has left or entered its viewport. This check will be run for each object before render is called.

Comment: You are right. The problem is not only the rendering but the collision detection too. And collision can cause a lot of delay but i don't care about it for know. The render method except rendering can also run expensive algorithms (which i call brains :p) and i can't know the code of these algorithms because the game programmer is gonna create them. So the fewer the engine is running the better will be for poor ram :p I will check these Quadtrees, never heard heard them before :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all your objects in a 2 dimensional grid where the grid represents your whole scene. Then you can easily iterate over only the ones visible on the screen. And collision detection becomes easier now.

The size of the cells are up to you. Try different sizes an see which one works best